# Django admin database error on Bluehost shared hosting

Tags: python, django, django-admin, shared-hosting

Using django with sqlite3 on bluehost shared hosting.
If I try to view any of my models (Users, for example) via the admin panel I get an error, but if I manually enter the url to any specific object, there is no problem.

So,

www.domain.com/admin/auth/user/

throws this error:

> Database error.
>
> Something's wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make
>   sure the database is readable by the appropriate user.

But,

www.domain.com/admin/auth/user/20/

www.domain.com/admin/auth/user/add/

www.domain.com/admin/auth/user/20/delete/

works fine.

The error is so generic, I'm not sure how to debug this. Any ideas on generating a traceback?

**Edit #1:**

If I'm understanding the docs correctly, django doesn't require username/password to access a dbsqlite3 database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/

*Settings.py*

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Deployment Settings
USE_SSL = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
```

**Edit #2:**

Perms for db.sqlite3 file: 
-rw-r--r-- 1 adminusername

Comment: What are the permissions for the SQLite file?

Comment: share the settings.py database profile.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. See edits to main question.